# Setting up a swapfile in local SSD (temporary drive) in Azure VM

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I'm using a DS4 Azure VM (Ubuntu 14.04). It comes with a 56GB local SSD.

I need to set up a 25GB swapfile in this local SSD. When I do `df -h` in the VM, I can see that it seems to be mapped to the `/mnt/` folder. Following is the entire output:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        29G   22G  6.4G  77% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev             14G  4.0K   14G   1% /dev
tmpfs           2.8G  472K  2.8G   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none             14G     0   14G   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
none             64K     0   64K   0% /etc/network/interfaces.dynamic.d
/dev/sdb1        56G   97M   56G   1% /mnt
```

However, if I try to initialize a swapfile in `/mnt`, it still gets added to the available disk space in `/dev/sda1`.

What do I need to do to set up my swap file? An illustrative example would be great. Thanks in advance.

---

I normally use the following commands to set up a swapfile:

```
sudo fallocate -l 25G /swapfile
sudo chmod 600 /swapfile
sudo mkswap /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile
```

---

**Update:**

I went into `/etc/waagent.conf`, and tweaked the followed:

```
# Format if unformatted. If 'n', resource disk will not be mounted.
ResourceDisk.Format=y

# File system on the resource disk
# Typically ext3 or ext4. FreeBSD images should use 'ufs2' here.
ResourceDisk.Filesystem=ext4

# Mount point for the resource disk
ResourceDisk.MountPoint=/mnt

# Create and use swapfile on resource disk.
ResourceDisk.EnableSwap=y

# Size of the swapfile.
ResourceDisk.SwapSizeMB=26000
```

After this, I resized (and consequently rebooted) my Azure VM from the portal. Currently I can't tell whether the settings have taken effect. Are my settings correct and what's the best way to ensure they've taken effect?

Answer (score 1):

You are right, we should modify `/etc/waagent.conf` to add a swap file.

By modifying the /etc/waagent.conf file and setting the following **3 parameters** a swap file will be created in the directory defined by ResourceDisk.MountPoint

```
ResourceDisk.Format=y  
ResourceDisk.EnableSwap=y    
ResourceDisk.SwapSizeMB=26000
```

Then we should restart walinuxagent:

```
service walinuxagent restart
```

Commands to show the new swap space in use after agent restart:

```
dmesg | grep swap


root@ubuntu:~# swapon -s
Filename        Type    Size    Used    Priority
/mnt/swapfile   file   26623996  0      -1

root@ubuntu:~# df -Th
Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev           devtmpfs  3.4G   12K  3.4G   1% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs     697M  412K  697M   1% /run
/dev/sda1      ext4       29G  869M   27G   4% /
none           tmpfs     4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none           tmpfs     5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none           tmpfs     3.5G     0  3.5G   0% /run/shm
none           tmpfs     100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/sdb1      ext4       99G   26G   68G  28% /mnt
```

> I resized (and consequently rebooted) my Azure VM from the portal

I resized my VM, and the swap file does **not** lose.

> Are my settings correct and what's the best way to ensure they've
>   taken effect?

After modify the `/etc/waagent.conf` and restart `walinuxagent`, we can use `swapon -s` to check it.

Comment: `swapon -s` doesn't show this swap file, so clearly I'm still missing it. When I do `service walinuxagent status`, I get `walinuxagent stop/waiting`. If I next do `service walinuxagent restart`, I get the error I've documented here: http://serverfault.com/questions/837306/restarting-process-gives-start-rejected-send-message-error Lastly, if I then do `sudo service walinuxagent restart`, I get `stop: Unknown instance: 
walinuxagent stop/pre-start, process 11498`. How can I fix this?

Comment: @HassanBaig  I think we should remove the walinuxagent and re-install it by apt-get, please check the answer in server fault.

Comment: Will this require any server reboot, or disrupt anything currently going on? I'm concerned since these changes would be taking place directly on the production server.

Comment: @HassanBaig I remove it from my VM, not need to reboot Azure VM, it just delete configuration and/or data files of walinuxagent. Also you can setup a test VM and test it again.

Comment: @HassanBaig please backup your waagent.conf and copy a new conf file to that directory, then try to start walinuxagent.

Comment: As in, do this in addition to uninstalling waagent? Or what?

Comment: Not uninstall waagent, just replace it's config file.

Comment: Hmmm, so basically just copy the exact file (with the swap settings), backup the original one, and rename this new file as `waagent.conf`. And then restart? If that's what I should do, then isn't that going to have the same effect as restarting with the original file intact?

Comment: Have you modified the configuration file? except `ResourceDisk.Format=y  
ResourceDisk.EnableSwap=y    ResourceDisk.SwapSizeMB`  If yes, we  should modify them to original.  this error because configure is not correct.

Comment: please check `/var/log/waagent.log and /var/log/cloud-init.log`,we can find it's logs